# VS Code Emmet is there a way to trigger Expansion ONLY on tab and disable on Enter

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, emmet

To start Thank you for you time,

I use VS Code and Emmet and .sass. My question is if there is a work around to disable expanding with the ***Enter*** key, because in Sass when I type `h1` and press Enter I get `height: 1px` and I only want the Abbrevation Expantion with ***Tab*** and when hitting ***Enter*** I want to go in a new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> from completing an emmet expansion by setting this to `off`

> Editor : Accept Suggestion On Enter  // set to `off`

It disables using <kbd>Enter</kbd> from working on ALL suggestions - not just those related to emmet - but <kbd>Tab</kbd> works on those others.  I don't see an emmet-only way to disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> from completing an expansion.

Comment: Thank you that made my day. I wasn't looking for that I just searched all the time for expanding